# Very intermittent -- DataTables warning: table id=... - Invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am having a very intermittent problem with Ajax and Datatables.

Here's my JavaScript Code:

```
var table_1 = $('#task_runner_table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../static/files/task_runner.json',
          "columns": [
             null,
             null
             ],
             "columnDefs": [{ targets: [0], className: 'dt-body-right' },
                           { targets: [1], className: 'dt-body-center' }],
        "ordering": false,
        "pageLength": 30,
        "searching": false,
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
    } );

var table_2 = $('#task_runner_stats').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../static/files/tr_stats.json',
          "columns": [
             null,
             null
             ],
             "columnDefs": [{ targets: [0], className: 'dt-body-right' },
                           { targets: [1], className: 'dt-body-center' }],
        "ordering": false,
        "pageLength": 30,
        "searching": false,
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
    } );

setInterval(function(){
        table_1.ajax.reload();
    }, 2999)

setInterval(function(){
        table_2.ajax.reload();
    }, 2971)
```

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card-block">
                <table id="task_runner_table" class="display" data-order="[]"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">

            <div id="event_chart2"></div>
            <div id="event_chart3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-6">
            <table id="task_runner_stats" class="display" data-order="[]"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue has to do with `table_2`.  If I comment out `table_2` and the setInterval for it, I do not have any issues. But when I run it, I get an error:

**DataTables warning: table id=task_runner_stats - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1**

It doesn't occur immediately -- the page will refresh a few times and then the error will appear.  Sometimes it runs for 5 minutes, sometimes 30seconds before the error appears.

when I go to the `developer tools --> network --> response`. I always get the same valid JSON structure:

`{"data": [["max_queue", ###], ["max_pool", ##3], ["max_running", ###]]}## Heading ##`

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Try keeping dev-tools open the whole time and checking the _Network_ tab when a failure happens. I'd say you're just missing when an error occurs.

Comment: I kept the network open and saw how the error occurs, but am not sure how to address it.  The Timing tab shows the "Waiting (TTFB)" as taking 2+ seconds.  The reason I never saw the error is that after I clear the warning alert, and then double click on the tr_stats.json in the left column, the correctly formed JSON appears.  So it seems to be throwing the error due to a timeout when reading my JSON.  Is there a way to increase the timeout buffer?

Comment: not sure if its directly related, but adding **"bDestroy": true** helped.  The warning still shows up, just less frequently.

Comment: the JSON file that creates the DataTable is read off a network mount that seems to cause the Network TTFB to spike intermittently up to 1+ seconds.  When I try reading a local JSON file, it stops failing.  So my question is:  **is there a way to force the datatable to wait longer or just wait indefinitely until it gets the JSON data?**